# Recursion in jQuery event

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion, jquery-events

This event is attached to a set of elements:

```
var elems = $(this).filter(function(){
  ...
});
```

How can I trigger a change event on these elements within a change event handler, but ignore the current element?

```
elems.bind('change input', function(){

  // do some stuff...

  // then trigger change, but not on "this", to avoid the recursion issue
  elems.change(); 

});
```

Basically I want ot ignore `this` from `elems`, but only in my "manual" change()-call above...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var elems = $(this).filter(function(){
  ...
});

elems.bind('change input', function(){


  // then trigger change, but not on "this", to avoid the recursion issue
  elems.not(this).change(); 

});
```

Though I must say, this scenario looks like a poor design issue.
When element get changed it sets a change event callback to some elements including him self...  sound awkward and that recursion is just a **symptom** to other bigger problem...

It probably can be done in a a lot cleaner way then this.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
elems.not(this).change();
```

Comment: but I want to keep that event on all elements, I just don't want to be included when I trigger change manually

Answer (score 2):

You can just filter out the current element:

```
elems.not(this).trigger('change'); // or just .change()
```